# /proc/stat column number on different platforms

Tags: linux

The column number of /proc/stat is different on various on different platforms. Will the meaning of the i-th column change ?

For example, the man page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html gives ten value columns, but on my linux only showns eight columns.

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/stat
cpu  148894509 5214 64962656 4534478045 18407228 6482288 24487520 0
cpu0 71026365 2633 34928452 2246110103 18371398 6482288 21933024 0
cpu1 77868143 2580 30034204 2288367942 35829 0 2554495 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the link clearly states kernel versions that start implementing those columns:

> steal (since Linux 2.6.11)
>
> guest (since Linux 2.6.24)
>
> guest_nice (since Linux 2.6.33)

If your kernel version is less than 2.6.24, then you will see 8 columns. But the order and meaning of columns remain the same.